# How can I use attribute word_store in another function of the same class AttributeError: 'Hangman' object has no attribute 'word_store'

Tags: python, class, attributeerror

```
class Hangman:  #class hangman
    def Word_list(self):
        result=random.choice(['debtee', 'mob', 'freight', 'torment', 'freight train', 'boredom','botcher', 'bothersome', 'bungler', 'continuation', 'officially', 'practically']) 
        word_len=len(result)
        word_store=list(result)     

    def main_game(self):
        #print('The word is %s long'%Word_list.list_result_len)
        spaces=[]
        for space in range(1,10):

            spaces.append('_ ')
            chance=10
        print(spaces)   
        for x in range(1,10):


            choose =input('Kindly choose a letter that you think this word contains :')
            if choose in self.word_store:     #facing the issue here
                position=self.word_store.index(choose)
                spaces[position]= choose
                print(spaces)
                print("Great!! This letter is present in the word, Keep Going")

            else:
                chance=chance-1
                print("Sorry this letter does not exist in the word")
                hangman_figure(chance)
```

Comment: put code in question, not in comment. And when you edit question then select code and use button `{}` to correctly format code.

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: describe problem in question's body, not in title

Comment: in `class` you have to use `self.word_store` to have access to variable in all functions. You should learn it in any tutorial about classes and Object Oriented Programming (`OOP`) in Python.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion @furas.
but u can see I am already using self.word_store in my function. I am unable to figure out what I am doing wrong in the class.

Comment: no, you don't use `self.` in `word_store=list(result)` - you have to use `self.` in all places - `self.word_store=list(result)`

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `self.` in all functions to create and use class variable

```
  self.word_store = list(result)
```